# idangero.us slider current slide and max slide

Tags: jquery

I'm using idangero.us slider (http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/index.php) for displaying multiple images. When you hover over the image, I'm displaying a DIV that says "Image X of X". This kind of works, but the total count is always wrong. My javascript code is

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    speed: 600,
    autoplay: 5000,
    autoResize: true,
    preventLinks: true,
    calculateHeight: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    pagination: '.pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    onSlideChangeEnd: function () { 
       $(".start_index").html(mySwiper.activeIndex)
    }
})

$(".start_index").html("1")
$(".end_index").html(mySwiper.slides.length)
```

In my swiper-container div, I have the following which should be updated as the slides are moved:

```
<div class="ImageIndex">
    Image <span class="start_index">2</span> of <span class="end_index">3</span>
</div>
```

Has anyone done anything like this that could help?

Comment: It's now mySwiper.activeIndex

Answer (score 1):

```
var pressSwiper = new Swiper('.press-container', {
    mode : 'vertical',
    slideClass : 'press-slide',
    wrapperClass : 'press-wrapper',
    calculateHeight : true,
    watchActiveIndex: true,
    onSlideChangeEnd: function () { 
        $(".presSlidesActive").text(pressSwiper.activeIndex +1);
    }
});



$( ".pressArrow.prev" ).click( function() { pressSwiper.swipePrev();   });
$( ".pressArrow.next" ).click( function() { pressSwiper.swipeNext();   });

$(".presSlidesActive").text("1");
$(".presSlidesFrom").text(pressSwiper.slides.length);

$( ".pressArrow.veryPrev" ).click( function() { pressSwiper.swipeTo(0);   });
$( ".pressArrow.veryNext" ).click( function() { pressSwiper.swipeTo(pressSwiper.slides.length-1);   });
```